# psycopg2 return single quotes instead of double for json_agg

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to get json data from database (Python 3.8 / psycopg2 2.8.6 / PostgreSQL 12) with double quotes , but for now it's in single quotes:

```
sql = "select json_agg(prices) FROM prices WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '6 MONTH')"
connection = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='products', user='postgres', password='123456')
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
response = cur.fetchone()
return str(response)
```

Response (single quotes):
`[{'id': 1, 'date': '2020-09-29T22:36:24.942066+03:00', 'price': 697.14, ...`

But when I perform the same query via pgAdmin it is with double quotes as expected:

`[{"id": 1, "date": "2020-09-29T22:36:24.942066+03:00", "price": 697.14, ...`

Am I missing something?

P.S. I know that I can replace it manually but I want to find better solution.

Comment: When you retrieve `jsonb`, psycopg2 turns it into a python object for you.  If you want to get json, then `import json` and then `return json.dumps(response)`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks, it's much better but it adds additional [] like `[[{"id": 1,...]]` (two brackets at the start and end instead of one), so I just need to use `return json.dumps(response[0])`

Comment: The thing is that `json.dumps` returns a string. Is that something you can work with?

Comment: Yes, string is ok for me as it is response from flask endpoint

Comment: You can use `json_agg(prices)::text` to cast the json output into text to pass back to python as a string